# DB2 Child Table Not Working - Create Table

Tags: sql, db2

I have a bit of a task before me. (DB2 Database)
I need to create a table that will be a child table (is that what it is called in SQL?)
I need it so that it has a foreign key constraint with my other table, so when the parent table is modified (record deleted) the child table also loses that record.

Once I have the table, I also need to populate it with the data from the other table (if there is an easy way to `UPDATE` this).

If you could point me in the right direction, this would help alot, as I do not even know what syntax to look for.

The table I have in place:

```
create table titleauthors (
    au_id       char(11),
    title_id    char(6),
    au_ord      integer,
    royaltyshare    decimal(5,2));
```

The table I am creating:

```
create table titles (
    title_id    char(6),
    title       varchar(80),
    type        varchar(12),
    pub_id      char(4),
    price       decimal(9,2),
    advance     decimal(9,2),
    ytd_sales   integer,
    contract    integer,
    notes       varchar(200),
    pubdate     date);
```

I need the title_id to be matched with the title_id from the parent table AND use the ON DELETE CASCADE syntax to delete when that table is deleted from.

My Attempt:

```
CREATE TABLE BookTitles (
title_id    char(6) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT BookTitles_title_id_pk REFERENCES titleauthors(title_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
title       varchar(80) NOT NULL,
type        varchar(12),
pub_id      char(4),
price       decimal(9,2),
advance     decimal(9,2),
ytd_sales   integer,
contract    integer,
notes       varchar(200),
pubdate     date)
;
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of comments, first:

1. A parent table must have a primary or unique key in order for it to be referenced by a foreign key.
2. Your post implies that you want BookTitles to be the child table (even though this seems backwards to me).  Logically, I would think that you want the logic to be:  "If you delete a book from the BookTitles table, then the rows from the TitleAuthors table should be deleted, too" -- not the other way around.  From your description of the TitleAuthors table, the logical primary key is (TITLE_ID, AU_ID).  This would preclude it from being a 
   parent table to BookTitles, which does not contain AU_ID.
3. It's a lot easier to add constraints after creating a table than to try and specify it in the CREATE TABLE STATEMENT.

---

Assuming that you want your parent/child relationship reversed (BookTitles as parent, TitleAuthors as child):

```
CREATE TABLE BookTitles (
    title_id    char(6) NOT NULL,
    title       varchar(80) NOT NULL,
    type        varchar(12),
    pub_id      char(4),
    price       decimal(9,2),
    advance     decimal(9,2),
    ytd_sales   integer,
    contract    integer,
    notes       varchar(200),
    pubdate     date
);

alter table booktitles 
   add primary key (title_id);

alter table titleauthors
   add constraint fk_booktitles
   foreign key (title_id) 
   references booktitles (title_id)
    on delete cascade;
```

This will cause records in TitleAuthors to be deleted if the title is deleted from BookTitles.